# Using $routeParams inside ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pass a `$routeParams` value to filter ng-repeat data. Here is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('BookCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams' function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('books.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.books = data;
        $scope.slug = $routeParams.slug;
    });
}]);
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="container" role="document" ng-repeat="book in books | filter:{slug: {{slug}}}">
    <p>{{book.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Is possible to do this? I try with the above code, but returned a syntax error:

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$parse/syntax?p0=

Comment: Have you tried it? And if so, what were the results?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and add the syntax error you get. Otherwise you're just going to get speculation and more comments/questions like this ;)

Comment: @marcelo2605 Just remove `{{}}` around `slug`

Comment: Also have you injected `$http` service? It doesn't seem to be here

Comment: @RahilWazir Fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed:

```
<div class="container" role="document" ng-repeat="book in books | filter:{slug:  slug }">
```